# Cordova ionic mp3 ID3 tags

Tags: jquery, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am building an mp3 player app using cordova and ionic framework. I came across a situation where i need to access the id3 tags like title etc.. of the mp3 stored in the user's phone. Is there a plugin or something to do that? Please explain how to do it.

Comment: Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader/issues/39) could help you.

Comment: No plugin can help you, but you can use this https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader